# Angular ChartJS scales min value and call back not working

Tags: angular, chart.js

I am trying to use ChartJS line chart on my Angular 9 application. I want to scale Y axes of my chart to display values from 0 (instead of from the minimum value) and to add '%' mark after value My code looks like below. Any idea what is the problem?

```
this.chart = new Chart(this.chartRef.nativeElement, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels,
        datasets: [
          {
            data: dataPoints, 
            borderColor: '#00AEFF',
            fill: false
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            display: true
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            display: true,
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
              suggestedMin: 0,
              min: 0,
              callback(value, index, values) {
                 return value + '%';
              }
            },
            afterBuildTicks(chart) {

            }
          }],
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: Hi, I just tried creating a simpler version, https://angular-pzqpoh.stackblitz.io. but it gives the error, 'Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined'

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pzqpoh

Comment: no, because I am getting this error 'ERROR
Error: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined' I am not able to reproduce it.

Comment: What is your issue? Is chart not rendering ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a number of errors that need to be fixed in order to work.

In Angular 8, `@ViewChild` expects a second parameter

```
@ViewChild('lineChart', {static: true}) private chartRef;
```

The chart should be created inside `ngOnInit`, the canvas is not yet available at the time when the `Component` is constructed. This is basically where the `Error: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined` comes from.

`scales.yAxes.ticks.callback` inside the chart `options` is not properly defined as a function.

Also the `canvas` needs to be enclosed in a `div`.

Please have a look at the amended [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uzd3t1)